# Exporting type-operators from modules

Tags: haskell, types, module, type-level-computation

How do you export type-operators? Considering they can clash with normal operators, there must be a special syntax if it's possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer in section [7.4.4 of the GHC User's Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html), which states:

> There is now some potential ambiguity in import and export lists; for example if you write `import M( (+) )` do you mean the *function* `(+)` or the *type constructor* `(+)`? The default is the former, but with `-XExplicitNamespaces` (which is implied by `-XExplicitTypeOperators`) GHC allows you to specify the latter by preceding it with the keyword `type`, thus:
>
> ```
> import M( type (+) )
> ```

Although it doesn't seem like you actually need to specify `-XExplicitNamespaces`, maybe `-XExplicitTypeOperators` is a typo meant to be `-XTypeOperators`. Some more empirical evidence for this:

```
★ → :set -XExplicitTypeOperators
Some flags have not been recognized: -XExplicitTypeOperators
```

Comment: Please file a bug report against that documentation on the GHC Trac. If you don't want to, let me know and I'll do it. In fact, let me know either way :).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than *importing* a type, you may want to only *export* a type operator.

I defined `type a * b = ...`, but exporting `(*)` exported the prelude function `(*)` rather than the type synonym. Similar to the answer above, to *export* a type operator, you can use the syntax:

```
module Foo (type (*)) where

  type a * b = ...
```